# Adding HTML File with Image to Intranet

Tags: images, html, hyperlink, upload, intranet

Im a complete dope regarding this kind of thing so forgive the question if it appears dumb.

A friend who works in a very well-known computer gaming company has afforded me the opportunity to advertise my business to their employees through the intranet.

He has been given access to the intranet, but neither of us know where to go from here. I have created a "2-sided" flyer and saved them as HTML files with Photoshop. The files contain images which can be clicked on so that the viewer can be redirected to my site. Also, Photoshop automatically created a separate folder containing the images on both sides of the flyer.

We/I would greatly appreciate some advice on how to go about uploading this to the intranet so that the employees/viewers can visit the page and immediately see the flyer in its full glory and then proceed to click on the hyperlinks added and be redirected to my site via their devices (computer/tablet/phone).

Thanks in advance for any replies/help.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, you have so much to learn that it's hard to know where to begin.
The best would be for you to find a knowledgeable person to help.

You don't even describe the local network of that company, which is the
most important part. Information to be visible to everyone must be stored
on some central server that every employee consults every day.
Normally, in that case, you would incorporate in a home-page
a teaser message with a link that would refer the viewer to your 2-pager.

Might I suggest that it would be much simpler for you
to advertise your business to their employees through an email,
if you were given the opportunity to email all of them.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the reply. The email is potentially a much simpler idea if we get the permissions of course. Re. the description of the local network for the company, what exactly is needed? My guy wont want to divulge/share any sensitive info for IS reasons

Comment: You really need help from somebody inside the company - they must have an IT guy who would already know this. A short talk with him would answer all your questions.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the advice - much appreciated. Ill see if we can hassle IT to help. Tricky though as I was lucky enough to get the ad opportunity for free so dont want to go putting people out of their way - an indication perhaps of how naive I was to think it that simple in the first place. In any case, cheers again.